# Counting lattice polytopes by volume

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, let $\mathcal{P}(n,B)$ be the set of $n$-dimensional convex polytopes $\Delta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, taken up to integral, unimodular affine transformations, whose vertices lie in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and whose Lebesgue volume is bounded above by $B$.
It is not difficult to see that the set $\mathcal{P}(n,B)$ is finite.

Is there any known asymptotics for the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(n,B)$ as $n \to +\infty$ and/or $B \to +\infty$?

Do these asymptotics get more pleasing if we consider the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}\left(n,\frac{B}{n!}\right)$, *i.e.* if we consider the integral volume of polytopes instead of the Lebesgue one?

Are these asymptotics related to the number of simplices with which one can triangulate $\Delta \in \mathcal{P}(n,B)$?

I could not find anything in the literature, but I am not an expert in convex geometry or combinatorics, so I unfortunately do not know the literature very well.
Thank you very much!

Comment: What equivalence on polytopes are you using to do these counts?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @Nate! You are absolutely right, I should specify that I am taking polytopes up to integral, unimodular affine transformations, and also that I am taking them to be of full dimension. I edited the question.